# Bootstrap carousel responsive image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have some problem with bootstrap carousel. When I make the image on slider which have resolution `2000px X 500px` the slider is looks fine and perfect in dekstop screen size. But when I open my page in mobile version the slider is become very small on top of the page. I just want to make the slider image on the real size with responsive image strecth.

This is my complete code on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/s3upxcyq/1/

Please anyone help me with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
img {
    height: 300px !important;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```